# Android ListView multiple choice mode keep rows highlighted

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have a List View that keeps the clicked items highlighted, right now when you click an item its getting highlighted but only one at a time, even if the multipleChoice is set

the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/row_background_selector"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#09ffffff"/>
```

row_background_selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

</selector>
```

is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible but is not *multipleChoice* mode

```
mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceCallback());
```

where *MultiChoiceCallback* implements *AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener*

```
private class MultiChoiceCallback implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener { ... }
```

read more about [ActionMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it using a COntextual Action Bar here you have an example http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB